# Angular: Can't switch radio button in firefox using arrow keys

Tags: angular, typescript, firefox, radio-button, angular-validation

In my Angular app, I have a radio button component. Everything works, except that in Firefox I can't switch focus between radio buttons using the arrow keys (in Chrome, this works.).

I have noticed that if I remove *formControl* from my input element arrow keys start working - but ofc I want to have validation.

```
// control is a AbstractControl
<input type="radio"
   [id]="radioid"
   [name]="name"
   [formControl]="control"
   [value]="value"
   />

<label [for]="radioid">
     <ng-content></ng-content>
</label>
```

Any ideas of what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: I just tried out a radio button on chrome and firefox and it worked fine. Did you add the same formControl for all radio button options? Try out if [this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-reactive-forms-101-88qvnv?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html) works for you

Comment: You are only showing one radio button, please provide a reproducible example, preferably on stackblitz.

Comment: Very well, I'll come back with a stackblitz example

Comment: It appears the issue might be in my usage of 'formControl': when attempting to re-create the issue at stackblitzt I get the error "Can't bind to 'formControl' since it isn't a known property of 'input'." - which I strangely don't get when running my code locally. Concluding that I probably should use formControlName instead of just formControl.